# Solve PDE numerically

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am looking for some $f:[0,1]^2 \rightarrow R^+_0$ with

\begin{align} 
\lambda f(x,y)-\frac{1}{2}\Delta f(x,y)=x+y 
\end{align}

for $\lambda > 0$, with boundary conditions

\begin{align}
f^1(0,y)-f^2(0,y)&=c_1, \quad \forall y \in [0,1] \\
f^1(1,y)&=c_2, \quad \forall y\in[0,1] \\
f^1(x,0)&=c_3, \quad \forall x\in[0,1] \\
f^1(x,b)&=c_4, \quad \forall x\in[0,1]
\end{align}

where $\Delta$ defines the Laplace operator and $f^1:=\frac{d}{dx}f(x,y), \ f^2:=\frac{d}{dy}f(x,y)$.

I would like to solve this problem numerically but I don't know how to handle the first boundary condition. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: The PDE you are trying to numerically solve for is called the inhomogeneous Helmholtz equation and you have inhomogeneous boundary conditions. The usual thing to do is to reformulate the problem so you get homogeneous boundary conditions. Then, once you have done that, see [here](https://math.missouristate.edu/assets/Math/li.pdf) (up to page 4) for help with the homogeneous version. After that, I'm sure you can do a google search to find information about your particular problem.

Comment: Thank you verry much for your answer, but i don't know how to get homogeneous boundary conditions :/  So in this way, the Problem can't be solved numerically?